# How can I return JSON response in case of 500 error?

Tags: django

Let's say I want to send an email through ajax, and I have this code in my method:

```
    send_mail(
        subject='subject',
        messagex='message',
        from_email='some_mail@domain.com',
        recipient_list=['some_mail@domain.com']
    )
```

As you can see I made an error and instead of `message`, I passed `messagex` field.  And I get

```
AttributeError at /contact
'TypeError' object has no attribute 'message'
```

How can I nicely pass this message as `{error: "'TypeError' object has no attribute 'message'"}` so it could be used in frontend?

I tried using `except Exception as e`, but it doesn't catch it, as it is an error, not an exception.

Any solutions?

**edit:**

```
try:
    send_mail(
        subjexct='subject',
        messagex='message',
        from_email='some_mail@domain.com',
        recipient_list=['some_mail@domain.com']
    )
except Exception as e:
    return JsonResponse({'message': _(e.message)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: `except Exception` certainly *would* capture that error; I can only think that you must have put it in the wrong place.

Comment: Can you please share the whole try-catch part of your code?

Comment: @cagrias: Added

Comment: @DanielRoseman Please check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are catching the `TypeError` alright, but `TypeError` doesn't have a message attribute. It has `.args`

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    return JsonResponse({'error': _(e.args[0])}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Nice, thank you very much. Is it possible to catch all type of errors?

Comment: Exception already catches almost all errors, the ones it doesn't are not things that you want to be cached, like KeyboardInterrupt or SystemExit

Comment: So `_(e.args[0])` will display ALL errors correctly? All exceptions have that arg?

Comment: `except Exception as e:` catches whatever the error is raised in the try block, and yes, all exceptions have args unless you especially create an exception class and delete the args attribute, but it should be noted that `.args` may not be always populated, so you probably should check if args is empty or not before trying to get the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Django will always return an internal server error in case of one, you don't have to get the error with `try except`. So do not try to get the exception in backend, what you have to do is to get the exception directly in the Ajax error call. Check out the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    data: datam,
    url: request_url,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(response) {
        // Success function
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        if(jqXHR.status === 500) {
            alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to get a message from BE